# Can't access selector when passing in HTML content dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have some buttons on a page which respond upon being clicked. I am now passing this HTML content (containing these buttons) into an empty div using jQuery.

```
$('#main').html($('#sectionC').html())
```

`#main` is the empty div and `#sectionC` is the div containing these buttons. Ok?
Everything displays properly. All of the buttons coming from `#sectionC` have a class of `.btn`, but the following script doesn't work when I pass this content in dynamically.

```
$('.btn').click( function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-active')
})
```

`$('.btn').click` simply doesn't get called at all when clicking on one of these buttons.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding event on dynamically added elements.

```
$('#main').on('click', '.btn', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('btn-active')
})
```

Comment: This fixes it! Not quite sure I understand why though. Thanks.

Comment: on is used to delegate the event to parent element could be document and it will take care of element which are not present at the time the  on binds the event and are added later.